90's fantasy book series with a warrior named Braccus, a flying sword and a shaman who transforms into a wolf
There was a female wizard, name started with a J.
A warrior, named Braccus, finds an enchanted flying sword. Also a barbarian shaman that could transform into a wolf.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How many books were in the series?  Can you describe the cover art?

I believe there was 4.

just to clarify, the warrior was called Braccus, not the flying sword?

Yes that was the Warrior's name

The edit made it so that the warrior with a sword was also a barbarian shaman who turned into a wolf, which seems highly unlikely.

Hi user174456, I tried to improve your question title so that it's less generic and more descriptive. Hope this helps!

It's The Zagor Chronicles, a sort of spin-off of the Fighting Fantasy gamebook range. One of the books in the series is loosely based on the gamebook Legend of Zagor. The series has its own Goodreads page, which confirms that there were indeed four books.
The barbarian is Anvar, the warrior is Braxus, and the wizard is Jallarial (who doesn't have a page on the Fighting Fantasy wiki for some reason)
From Anvar's page on the FF wiki:

Anvar was raised as a Barbarian of the Bear clan. When he discovered that he may transform into a wolf, he decided to reach the Crown Tower in Barrabang. in order the be healed by the Crown of Kings. On his way, he meets the Dwarf Stubble. Together, they fought Frost Orcs of the Ulgzen tribe [1], and help the Centaur Berrabur to investigate an old subterranean of the Grunnar inhabited by an old Rock Wyrm. [2]
After these events, they were recruited in the King’s Own Irregulars of the Amarillian army in Baldamand. During the aftermath of the Battle of Lake Faro, they help the warrior Braxus to escort the wizard Jallarial to Sanctuary. [3]
Before attending to the Battle of the Bottomless Pit, Anvar learns he was choose by the Red Wolf Spirit, and thus, have to learn the magic way. Hostile to magic, and embarrassed by the fact he was chosen by a different spirit than the Black Bear Spirit, protector of his own clan, he was first reluctant to held his new powers. [4]

I haven't found anything on Braxus's flying sword, though. But I do remember that he could find and equip a flying sword in the original Legend of Zagor.

OMG!!!! That's it!!!!!

Thank you so much!
